# Using Mail Merger on Mac, with Word 2016. Merge to Email is grayed out/

Tags: excel, email, ms-word, mailmerge

I am trying to use Mail merger on word 2016 using a mac; however, the merge to email field is grayed out. Is there a reason for this? I updated the MSOffice but this is not helping. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

According the below link you may just need to change your default mail settings.

https://keepcalmgetorganised.com.au/how-to-do-a-mail-merge-email-with-office-for-mac/